# TextBox aceitar números e vírgulas

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Estou precisando que um `textBox` aceite somente números e vírgulas.

Para aceitar números estou fazendo assim:

```
 private void textbox11_num(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("este campo aceita somente numero e virgula");
        }
    }
```

Porém desse modo ele não aceita virgula, como faria?

Comment: Por que não usa um NumericUpDown? É só marcar a opção pra ele trabalhar com decimal e pronto :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não sei se vai resolver tudo o que deseja, mas a solução normalmente é usar o [`MaskedTextBox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Se isso não resolver, ou terá que criar um controle próprio (ou pega um pronto melhor que o padrão), ou terá que fazer muita personalização nele (nem sempre dá o resultado esperado).

Se for insistir em personalizar o `TextBox` padrão, para controlar tudo o que é necessário é bem complicado para postar uma resposta aqui.

A não ser que só queira formatar no final da digitação, aí é simples, mas a experiência do usuário será bem prejudicada.

Uma outra alternativa para esse caso específico pode ser um [`NumericUpDown`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). A decisão é sua se atende bem.

Para fazer algo simples e só impedir o uso de outros caracteres, talvez isso resolva:

```
private void textBox11_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != ',')) {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("este campo aceita somente numero e virgula");
    }
    if ((e.KeyChar == ',') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)) {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("este campo aceita somente uma virgula");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/FilterKey.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Você deve verificar o KeyChar que está sendo recebido através do evento, desta forma:

```
private void textbox11_num(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Decimal && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Oemcomma && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.OemPeriod)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("este campo aceita somente numero e virgula");
    }
}
```

**Observação:**

Keys.Decimal (Ponto do teclado numérico)

Keys.Oemcomma (Vírgula abaixo das letras)

Keys.OemPeriod (Ponto abaixo das letras)

Answer (score 4):

Tente dessa forma:

```
 private void ValidaCaracter(KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8)
     {
         e.Handled = true;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
    private void textbox11_num(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == ',')
        {
            //troca o . pela virgula
            e.KeyChar = ',';

            //Verifica se já existe alguma vírgula na string
            if (textBox11.Text.Contains(","))
            {
                e.Handled = true; // Caso exista, aborte 
            }
        }

        //aceita apenas números, tecla backspace.
        else if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && !(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```